# JFreeChart - Shared Crosshair between Subplots

Tags: java, jfreechart, subplot

I would like to know how to have a shared Crosshair. I have a CombinedXYPlot with 5 XYPlots and when I click on the graph, I would like to have one single Crosshair that will appear on each SubPlot. For the moment, when I click on a SubPlot, the Crosshair appears only on this SubPlot :

```
List<XYPlot> lxyp = t.getSubplots();
        for (XYPlot xyp : lxyp) {
            xyp.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
            xyp.setDomainCrosshairLockedOnData(false);
            xyp.setRangeCrosshairVisible(false);
        }
```

Then, how to change the color and the thickness of this Crosshair ?

Thanks for your response !

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with `CombinedXYPlot`, but the method [setDomainCrosshairStroke()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#setDomainCrosshairStroke%28java.awt.Stroke%29) may available. This affords all the features of [BasicStroke](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html).

```
subplot1.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
subplot1.setDomainCrosshairPaint(Color.red);
subplot1.setDomainCrosshairStroke(new BasicStroke(1f));
...
subplot2.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
subplot2.setDomainCrosshairPaint(Color.blue);
subplot2.setDomainCrosshairStroke(new BasicStroke(1f));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response trashgod but it does not work. The Crosshair still appears only on the subPlot I have clicked, the subPlots are still independent.

Comment: Be sure to set the desired properties on _each_ subplot.